# How to initialise a vector with a function independent of index?

Tags: c++, lambda, stdvector

I want to define a vector with some number of ints and populate it with the results from the function `get_a_value()`. It can be done through a loop this way:

```
auto v = new std::vector<int>( 7 );
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    v->at(i) = get_a_value();
```

But there's some redundancy that makes me uncomfortable. Can this be solved with some lambda magic in just the vector initialisation?

```
auto v = new std::vector<int>( 7, /* something involving get_a_value() here */ );
```

The value of `get_a_value()` can be different in each call. And yes, I do need a pointer.

Comment: "And yes, I do need a pointer."  Not a _raw_ pointer, you don't.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: That is part of a university assignment. (The actual question isn't.)

Comment: Note: There are very very few cases where you want to dynamically allocate a `std::vector`.

Comment: I completely agree about pointers and dynamic allocation. I didn't remove it from my code example in case it would affect the solution.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want this:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(n); // reserve space only, no need to fill with default-constructed T's

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), n, get_a_T_value); // fill with n values
```

This is simplest and most efficient. I leave it to you to adapt it to your homework.